Movie about a black kid adopted in Israel
I think it was released at most 15 years ago; it was set in Israel (that's for sure), but I watched it dubbed in Italian, so I am not sure if it was in english or or ebrew.
This movie is about a black kid emigrated from Somaly (I think) adopted by an Israeli couple. It is about his life in that country, it also deals with jewish racism. 
At the end of the movie the kid becomes a doctor and goes back in his country with Médecins Sans Frontières and meets his mother. 
One scene I remember: he is already a teenager and is invited to a birthday party, but the father of the other guy/girl won't let him in (he slams the door in his face a couple of times), because according to him blacks immigrants are christians and are taking advantage of Israel.

Live and Become (2005)

I think this is the one which you are looking for.

In 1980 the black Falashas in Ethiopia are recognised as genuine Jews. In turn they are secretly carried to Israel. The day before the transport the son of a Jewish mother dies.

